# LEFT OUTER JOIN with LIMIT

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, limit

I'm trying to get a certain number of records from a table along with their associated data from another table:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM tblA a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tblB b ON a.id = b.target WHERE ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 0,40
```

It works, but the problem is that LIMIT seems to limit the number of results and not the number of records I find in A :(

Is there any way to get LIMIT to take into account only the records from A? Because a record from A may have many related records in B and I don't want to limit that

Comment: I want to clarify this statement: "`a record from A may have many related records in B and I don't want to limit that`". This means you want 40 records total from table A. Is that really what you want, or do you want up to 40 records from B per key in A?

Comment: yes that's what I want. B can have any number of records that link to a record from A, or have none. Basically B is like metadata for A. So I want to query 40 records from A, and get that metadata too if possible with the same query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting the limit in a sub-query, and joining on that.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM tblA WHERE ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 0,40
)
  AS a
LEFT JOIN
  tblB AS b
    ON a.id = b.target
```

Many RDBMS will support this, I have no idea about SQLite.

Comment: Can't use ORDER BY in a sub query, but otherwise on the right track.

Comment: So there's no way to do it with ORDER? And what's up with `LEFT JOIN`? won't that ignore any records from A that don't have associated records in B?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: You can use `order by` in a subquery as long as the subquery has as `limit` (or `top` in SQL Server.)

Comment: @thelolcat - `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are synonyms.  I'm just in the habit of writing the shorter form.  As far as my SQLFiddle example goes, this appears to work for your needs.